# How to Draw (directly) on Screen in Windows with Python?

Tags: python, windows, graphics, screen

I want to create visual hints for users on their screens, but I got struck finding a simple solution how to do basic drawings straight on the screen without limiting the user actions (under Windows with Python 3.x).

After a search the only - not properly working - solution I found was using wxPython. Here's the code:

```
import wx

# init
app=wx.App()
dc=wx.ScreenDC()

# set line and fill style
dc.SetBrush(wx.TRANSPARENT_BRUSH) 
dc.SetPen(wx.Pen((255, 0, 0), width=3, style=wx.PENSTYLE_SOLID))

# draw (x, y, width, height)
dc.DrawRectangle(100, 100, 200, 100)
```

The code draws on the screen, but the result barely becomes visible as the screen is redrawn (by Windows) very quick. I tried a work-around in repeating the drawing command with a for-loop, but also the flickering rectangle is barely visible (and this is nothing that I like to show to my clients).

A bit better (close to sufficient) is using a transparent TKinter window (without header) and display it for a - shorter - period of time. Here's the WORKING code of that (with one downside that is explained below the code):

```
from tkinter import *

def HighlightSection(Rect=(100,100,300,200), Color = 'red', Duration = 3):
    win= Tk()
    GeometryString = str(Rect[0])+'x'+str(Rect[1])+'+' \
                     +str(Rect[2])+'+'+str(Rect[3])
    win.geometry(GeometryString) # "200x100+300+250" # breite, höhe, x, y # 
    win.configure(background=Color)
    win.overrideredirect(1)
    win.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)
    win.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
    win.after(Duration * 1000, lambda: win.destroy())
    win.mainloop()
```

One thing here I could not make working: **Any chance to make this TKinter "window" click-trough?** Then this would be sufficient (close to quite good). As long as it is not click-trough the user cannot act in/under the highlighted area!

Is there a simple, solid solution to make draws (line, rectangles, text) on the screen and take it off again after a defined period of time? Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance, Ulrich!

Comment: Why not using the ```Pygame``` Library

Comment: Put your code inside the while loop. It will continue displaying objects

Comment: Looping on results in a weird flickering in conflict with Windows screen redraw.

Answer (score 0):

I believe drawing anything to the screen requires a window. The window can be partially transparent, but it needs to exist.

Something like this with PyQt5 may work for you. This will give you a transparent main window and draws a couple of lines:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Clear(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 270)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent")
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawLines(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawLines(self, qp):
        pen = QPen(Qt.blue, 2, Qt.SolidLine)

        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(20, 40, 250, 40)

        pen.setStyle(Qt.DashLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(20, 80, 250, 80)

        pen.setStyle(Qt.DashDotLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(20, 120, 250, 120)

        pen.setStyle(Qt.DotLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(20, 160, 250, 160)

        pen.setStyle(Qt.DashDotDotLine)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(20, 200, 250, 200)

        pen.setStyle(Qt.CustomDashLine)
        pen.setDashPattern([1, 4, 5, 4])
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(20, 240, 250, 240)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Clear()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Reference Source: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/painting/ - I modified it a bit to adjust the transparency.

Comment: Well, I just tried that and the result is just a window on screen. That's what I can do with dozens of other libraries... Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

This works, tested on macOS with Python 3.x.

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QPainter,
                         QPen,
                         QColor)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow,
                             QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt,
                          QCoreApplication,
                          QTimer)


class TransparentWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(
            self,
            x: int,
            y: int,
            width: int,
            height: int,
            pen_color: str,
            pen_size: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.highlight_x = x
        self.highlight_y = y
        self.highlight_width = width
        self.highlight_height = height
        self.pen_color = pen_color
        self.pen_size = pen_size
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        """Initialize the user interface of the window."""
        self.setGeometry(
            self.highlight_x,
            self.highlight_y,
            self.highlight_width + self.pen_size,
            self.highlight_height + self.pen_size)
        self.setStyleSheet('background: transparent')
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        """Paint the user interface."""
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(self.pen_color), self.pen_size))
        painter.drawRect(
            self.pen_size - 1,
            self.pen_size - 1,
            self.width() - 2 * self.pen_size,
            self. height() - 2 * self.pen_size)
        painter.end()


def highlight_on_screen(
        x: int,
        y: int,
        width: int,
        height: int,
        pen_color: str = '#aaaa00',
        pen_size: int = 2,
        timeout: int = 2):
    """Highlights an area as a rectangle on the main screen.

        `x` x position of the rectangle

        `y` y position of the rectangle

        `width` width of the rectangle

        `height` height of the rectangle

        `pen_color` Optional: color of the rectangle as a hex value;
                              defaults to `#aaaa00`

        `pen_size` Optional: border size of the rectangle; defaults to 2

        `timeout` Optional: time in seconds the rectangle
                            disappears; defaults to 2 seconds
        """
    app = QApplication([])
    window = TransparentWindow(x, y, width, height, pen_color, pen_size)
    window.show()
    QTimer.singleShot(timeout * 1000, QCoreApplication.quit)
    app.exec_()


highlight_on_screen(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

Resulting rectangle on screen

[image]

However, on macOS it is not possible to draw a window over the app bar. That shouldn't be an issue on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, it draws a white circle directly on the middle of the screen using a transparent window and PyQt. Everything behind the circle is interactable.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget

# Global variables for circle parameters
circle_radius = 50
outline_width = 2
outline_color = Qt.white

class GameOverlay(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()
        screen_geometry = screen.geometry()

        screen_width = screen_geometry.width()
        screen_height = screen_geometry.height()

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height)  # Set the overlay size to match the screen
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        # Draw a transparent background
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0)))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

        # Calculate the circle's center position
        circle_center_x = self.width() // 2
        circle_center_y = self.height() // 2

        # Draw the circle outline
        painter.setPen(QColor(outline_color))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0)))
        painter.drawEllipse(circle_center_x - circle_radius, circle_center_y - circle_radius,
                            circle_radius * 2, circle_radius * 2)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    overlay = GameOverlay()

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(overlay.update)
    timer.start(16)  # Update the overlay approximately every 16 milliseconds (about 60 FPS)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```